# how to fetch user interests from facebook via Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

```
$fql    =   "select name, interests , hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid=" . $uid;
```

I am using this query to fetch the user's interests and info.

But i am getting only name hometown_location , sex etc.

Answer (score 3):

You probably do not have the appropriate permissions: you need the **user_interests** permission for that. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ for the permissions listing.